# How to compare two strings in column in different tables in SQL

Tags: sql, sqlite, select, sql-like

I'm trying to write a Select statement to compare two columns.

I have these tables:

Table1

```
Code     Name
-----------------
ABC      Product1
DEF      Product2
GHI      Product3
```

and Table 2

```
Code2   Price
-------------
ABC-1   4
DEF-2   6
GHI-5   9
```

I want it to return

```
Name         Price
------------------
Product1     4
Product2     6
Product3     9
```

But my statement returns empty

```
Select Name, Price
From Table1, Table2
Where '%' + Code + '%' LIKE Code2
```

I have looked at similar problems and im not sure whats wrong in my code

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 3):

The `LIKE` pattern is always on the *right* of `LIKE`:

```
Select t1.Name, t2.Price
From Table1 t1 join
     Table2 t2
     on t2.Code2 like '%' || t1.Code || '%'
```

Notes:

- *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.
- *Always* use proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax.
- Qualify all column references in a query with multiple tables so you (and others) know where the columns come from.
- The string concatenation operator is `||`.
- The pattern you want is probably more like `t2.Code2 like t1.Code || '-%'` .